# Unable to perform chkdsk /r on external usb drive

Tags: external-hard-drive, chkdsk

I ran `chkdsk /f` on my external USB drive, it found some errors and corrected them. Then I try to run `chkdsk /r` (I also tried to add `/x`) on it, but it stays at 0% and the drive makes noise. Any ideas?

Comment: How long do you let it sit, and how big is the hard drive?

Comment: A few minutes, 500 GB. BTW, I can still access the files, I'm just worried some of them may be corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you let it sit and *not* try to access the files for at least a few hours, in reality at least a day before making an assumption that the drive might be bad. I usually do a chkdsk /f /r and let the drive sit for as long as possible. Every drive is different so I can't say you should see x amount of progress in x amount of time.